# DataAnnotations not using DisplayName Attribute in Error Messages

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

In my application, I'm using the `dataAnotation` as below for validating my ViewModels:

```
[DisplayName("Provider Business Name") ]
[StringLength(35)]
public string ProviderBusinessName
{
    get { return _providerBusinessName; }
    set { _providerBusinessName = value.ToUpper(); }
}
```

My environment is Asp.Net Webforms 4.0 and I'm manually invoking the validation with the following code:

```
dynamic context = new ValidationContext(datamodel, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
results = new List<ValidationResult>();
return Validator.TryValidateObject(datamodel, context, 
                                   results, validateAllProperties: true);
```

My problem is that the error messages are using the property name instead of the contents of the DisplayName attribute.  As far as I can see, the validation attributes should use the DisplayName in the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using Display property instead (that will make it work for your validation give you the power to use Resources there to be localized):

```
 [Display(Name = "Provider Business Name")]
```

Comment: I'm working on a .net 7 application and this solution doesn't work. For e.g., I'm getting ConfirmPassword display name as "Confirm Password" from a resource file, but the response in the web api is still showing ConfirmPassword

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
[Display(Name = "Provider Business Name")]
```

?